# Cant run Jest with Typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to run Typescript tests that run Typescript code with Jest.
I've tried to configure Jest with ts-jest in multiple shapes, but without success.

I obtain:

```
  node_modules/@polkadot/api/promise/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import _defineProperty from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty";

  ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import log4js from "log4js";
    > 2 | import { ApiPromise } from "@polkadot/api/promise";
        | ^
```

My jest.config.ts:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";
// Sync object
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  roots: ["./"],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  coverageDirectory: "../coverage",
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: "node",
  //setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.ts"],
  testMatch: ["**/?(*.)+(test).ts"],
  resetMocks: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!(@polkadot)/)"],
  //collectCoverage: true
};
export default config;
```

I run the tests with: `"jest --config src/test/jest.config.ts --detectOpenHandles"`

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I've also tried to execute my code [with TAP, but also unsuccessfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109197/nodejs-and-expressjs-app-times-out-with-tap). I would appreciate guidance to solve either of the problems, provided that the async tests can run.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup jest with Babel? `Jest` doesn't understand Typescript so it relies on babel for transpiling.

Comment: I used ts-node, that In principle should be enough, correct?

Answer (score 0):

This problem first and foremost has to do with the fact that all code in `node_modules` will not be transformed before Jest executes, and Jest can only process [CommonJS code](https://code-trotter.com/web/understand-the-different-javascript-modules-formats/). You have to add [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) in order to transform ESM code inside your `node_modules` to CJS. Have a look at [this example](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization) for how you actually set it up correctly.

Comment: I've added "  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!(@polkadot)/)"]" (updated in the question) but the same error occurs.